# how to add scroll bar inside the TextInput Box

Tags: python, kivy

i am showing some text inside the textinpuBox but that text length is much larger than the size of the textinputbox so how do i add vertical scroll bar in that textinputbox.

```
kivy file
BoxLayout:
   TextInput:
      id: tetx
      hint_text:""
```

```
python file
class MainApp(App): 
   a=" a long para " ;

   self.root.ids.tetx.hint_text= self.a
......
```

Comment: I think the `TextInput` supports scrolling by default, but I suspect it won't scroll the `hint_text`.

Comment: also you might try using `multiline: True` in your `TextInput` kv code

Comment: now multiline also not working with it when i reduce the size of screen some text get hidden

Comment: so can i show that text passage on label, so it will get scroll bar automatically

Comment: @ShrikantSawarkar is this solved or still an open question?

Comment: yes still open question @PalimPalim